# dropdown list does not let select items properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am making a project in ASP.NET WebForms. Although I have done it so many times but dropdown list is troubling me a lot this time.

I fetch items from DB and then add them to my dropdown list one by one using FOR loop. That works fine. But the problem is that I cannot select an item from list comfortably, whenever I try to select an item from the drop down list, it snaps the selection to the first element, it becomes very difficult to select the desired item.

How could I fix that?

Suppose I move my cursor over the 9th item in the list then also it selects the 1st and 9th item alternatively so fast that I see both of them as selected.

CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["familyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct family_head from family", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "family");
        con.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["family"].Rows.Count; i++)
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(ds.Tables["family"].Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

ASPX

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="30px" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Submit" Width="145px" BackColor="#465767" ForeColor="White" />

    <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="Button1_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Button1" Corners="All" Radius="10">
    </asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

A CSS Keyframes Animation is working in page background, Can that be a cause?

Comment: what is your browser ,please post code behind and .aspx html codes here.

Comment: Posted the code and markup.

Comment: I suppose the DropDownList1 have the issue ? and where you try to get the selection of it ? I see that you use the IsPostBack.

Comment: I have not coded the part where I will use the selected Item. Can you tell me what the exact issue is? Also I added the ispostback after your suggestion.

Comment: remove your script manager from content place holder and move it up in top of your markup after the form tag.

Comment: It behaves well with firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal If you add that after my suggestion then is must work.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal Did the viewstate is ON for this page and for that controls ?

Comment: I don't have a form tag, using Master Pages, so I added a scripmanager in the master right after the form tag. The ViewState is set to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some kind of confusion, as to how databinding works for WebControls. The best reference for that is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Under the assumption, that all the binding code for DropDownList1 is shown:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
```

shouldn't be neccesary, as the items shouldn't persist per PostBack. (At least I assume that, because all Items will be lost after each PostBack if the DataSource isn't bound again).

The DropDownList needs have the items on each PostBack, if you want to use the DropDownList. You are using

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

which means, that you don't bind the items again, if you have a PostBack. In the link posted above, you can see that Controls set their properties (like which item was selected before clicking a Button) during the LoadEvent, which means that the items need to be binded earlier in the lifecycle, like during OnInit.

Try something like this:

```
protected void BindDropDownList1()
{
 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["familyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 con.Open();
 adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct family_head from family", con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds, "family");
 con.Close();
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["family"].Rows.Count; i++)
   DropDownList1.Items.Add(ds.Tables["family"].Rows[i][0].ToString());
}

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
       this.BindDropDownList1();
       base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Another suggestion would be to you the DataSource property of the DropDownList, instead of `DropDownList1.Items.Add`. If you use this approach, you need to set the DataKeyValue and DataKeyMember properties of the DropDownList:

```
protected void BindDropDownList1()
{
 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["familyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 con.Open();
 adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct family_head from family", con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds, "family");
 con.Close();
 DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
 DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit**:
I think I found your error. You are using controls from the AjaxControlToolKit, but are still using the `ScriptManager`. For about 2 years, controls from the AjaxControlToolKit require the `ToolkitScriptManager`. Replace the `ScriptManager` with a `ToolkitScriptManager`.

Comment: That is not the issue at all. Please stay to the topic. I have issue while selecting items in DropDown List, the gui is not working perfect. when I move the mouse in the droppeddown list, the selection oscillates between the first and the hovered menu item. Why?

Comment: Have you checked for site for JavaScript errors? Try commenting out the RoundedCornersExtender and see it the problem persists.

Comment: Done using **ToolkitScriptManager**, didn't help! I would like you to know that it is all fine in Firefox AND IE.

Comment: I removed the CSS Keyframe animation from the page background and it works fine.  but I still don't know the cause.

Comment: Weird client side effects are often caused by JavaScript errors. Have a look at the developer tools and javascript console in chrome, maybe you can see some errors. I'm glad you were able to isolate your problem